# SQL: Counting occurrence of certain value from its first appearance till next five minutes and repeat the same for the next occurence again

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregation, data-analysis

I need to find the number of times a value say 34occurred from its first occurrence till next 5 minutes.

Then again do the same thing after 5 minutes, again fetch the record with value 20, see how many times it occurred til next 5 minutes for each device

Suppose say I have following table:

```
DevID      value             DateTime
--------------------------------------------------
99       20               18-12-2016 18:10
99       34               18-12-2016 18:11
99       34               18-12-2016 18:12
99       20               18-12-2016 18:15
23       15               18-12-2016 18:16
28       34               18-12-2016 18:17
23       15               18-12-2016 18:18
23       12               18-12-2016 18:19
99       20               18-12-2016 18:20
99       34               18-12-2016 18:21
99       34               18-12-2016 18:22
99       34               18-12-2016 18:23
99       34               18-12-2016 18:24
99       34               18-12-2016 18:25
```

I'm interested in number 34. I want to check the first appearance of number 34, get its time and then count how many times this number (34) occurred for the next 5 minutes. Basically fetch records from the first time of occurrence till occurrence +5minutes and count how many of them have 34 and if its more than 3 list that device name.

Repeat same for the next record with 34 till next 5 minutes. so in the case above, record 99 will had 34 first time at 18-12-2016 18:11 but then we did not get more than 3 record of 34 in next 5 minutes but however we again got 34 at 18-12-2016 18:21 and got more than 3 entries of 34 in next 5 minutes

So the expected output for the above table would be device id 99.

### Editted

I am interested in finding only value 34. So the extra complexity for finding all such repeated value in 5 minutes gap is not required.
Just want to know for which device we have 34 repeated more than 3 times(this should be changable i can hardcode this to 10 times as well) between a time interval of 5 minutes.

Comment: We would really need to know which _version_ of SQL you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.).

Comment: Could you post what've tried so far and what's the problem?

Comment: It's not clear to me what output you expect. You you please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the expected output based on the sample data you provided?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question over and over again?

Comment: @Biegel:using SQL server

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : updated expected output which is device 99 as that is the oly device which has 34 more than 3 times in 5 minutes gap

Comment: @Salman: i dont think i asked the same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient method is to use `lag()`/`lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(datetime, 2) over (partition by devid order by datetime) as next2_dt
      from t
      where value = 34
     ) t
where next2_dt <= dateadd(minute, 5, datetime);
```

This peaks ahead to the 2nd value and just compares the `datetime` of that value with the `datetime` on the current row.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done as follows:

```
SELECT DevID
FROM t
WHERE Value = 34
AND 2 <= (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM t AS x
  WHERE x.DevID = t.DevID
  AND x.Value = t.Value
  AND x.DateTime > t.DateTime
  AND x.DateTime < DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, t.DateTime)
)
GROUP BY DevID
```

You might want to replace `<` with `<=` depending on how you count 5 minutes.

Comment: This seems to work with the sample data set. Need to evaluate on real data set

Comment: @230490 . . . Although this is a viable solution , it is definitely not the most performant or simplest.

Comment: True that. Your solution is much faster

Answer (score 0):

please adjust to your RDBMS, but it should look something like this:

```
select b.*
from (
    select value, min(DateTime) as md
    from the_table
    group by value
) as a
join the_table as b
on a.value = b.value
and b.DateTime between a.md and a.md + interval'5'minute
```

Comment: I dont need for all value types. I need it for only value=34 and also this needs to be fetched for each device(may be partiioned by device id??)

Comment: @230490 Partitioning is probably not required here. Please provide sample of desired output.

Comment: For the data mentioned above. I just need to display Device ID of 99. If you look at the data only device with id 99 is having 34 more than 3 times in the gap of 5 minutes from  18-12-2016 18:21 to  18-12-2016 18:25. Changed the question for better understanding